# Javascript - Code executes once inside a loop with AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my javascript code I receive a value that tells me how many times I have to execute a piece of code but it executes just on time.

For example:

```js
var qtt = 3;
for (var i = 1; i <= qtt; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    $.get( "/set-serie", function(seriedata)
    {
        console.log('test ' + i);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The result is:

```
1
2
3
test 4
```

So, this just execute the code one time instead 3. And I don't understand why it put 4 at the end.

Comment: By the time the `$.get()` finishes, it is at the end of the loop and the variable has been incremented.

Comment: It's also a code smell that the ajax call is the exact same call for each iteration.

Comment: It's a duplicate of none of those questions. @zero298 turn your comment into an answer!

Comment: There should be a box with `3` on the left of `test 4` meaning that `test 4` has been logged `3` times.

Comment: @D_N your comment is confusing. You state his comment is an answer, and that it's not a duplicate... but the duplicate is that exact scenario.

Comment: @KevinB No, that's about a loop based on simple looping and an on-page event listener, and does not include an AJAX request, which is what is creating a problem for the OP. And previously there were three separate articles linked as duplicate, none of which were the same, which prompted my general comment.

Comment: @D_N This is absolutely a duplicate.  It may a combination duplicate of many of the duplicates listed, but it is still a duplicate.  The issue stems from not capturing the iteration counter into a context that won't be affected by the for loop.

Comment: @zero298 If it's a combination of a bunch of pages which are not duplicate, it's not duplicate.

Comment: The one duplicate adequately covers it. We don't need several.

Comment: To me it seem that OP doesn't know how the console works, seeing test only printed once and so thinking the function only ran once, assuming @ibrahimmahrir is correct. While OP can benefit from reading the close as duplicate question, I disagree that is in fact a duplicate.

Comment: That just makes it an X/Y, it doesn't make it not a duplicate.

Comment: @KevinB If you already know it, it makes sense as an answer. If you don't, it doesn't. Not very helpful.

Comment: You could see the question as a duplicate, but only in a very abstract way. Also, besides the issue from the 'duplicate',  OP asks why i is 4, where he expected 3. This is not explained in the 'duplicate'.

Comment: Cast your vote.

Comment: @D_N then it's too localized.